# Nightwatch.js without Java

Tags: java, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to use [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) without installing Java? There are official Selenium JavaScript bindings ([WebDriverJS](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs), [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)). Is there a reason Java is required?

Comment: So you mean you want to create e. g. some scripts/snippets to interact with the Selenium server wihout Java?

Comment: @NateStone Correct. I know how to drive browser with WebDriverJS, so I was surprised to see that Nightwatch.js requires Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now [documentation on the official site](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#chromedriver) on how to do it.

I had some trouble with the configuration, so I have created a sample repository with working code:

https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/mediawiki-nightwatch

Comment: That repository was really really helpful. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

I am catering to a JavaScript community so I am trying to run nightwatchjs locally without introducing Java myself.  I am certain that if you run a remote Selenium Server, that remote instance has to have the Java server running to pass off commands to the remote browser-specific driver. E.g.: ChromeDriver.

That said, I was under the impression that one could connect a [standard client](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) directly to a standard WebDriver (ChromeDriver) locally **without** having to stage the Java selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0.jar server. With nightwatchJS being the 1st client I have tried, it was very hard to find a configuration where that would work since all the documentation indicates what [Nate Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5484056/nate-stone) is saying above. All examples that I have seen indicate that the location of the selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0.jar needs to be stipulated:

```
selenium": {
  "start_process": true,
  "server_path": "lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar",
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/Users/greg.kedge/bin/chromedriver"
  },
  "log_path": "integration/log" }
```

He's what I can say: if you want nightwatch to start (and stop) the server for you for the duration of the tests ("start_process": true), it does seem to be necessary to run the Java server.

However, through much trial, if you want to start the ChromeDriver on your own on the command line, thereby having it up all the time, I **can** run the ChromeDriver without the Java Selenium standalone. CAVEAT: Only attempted on OS X so far... So, assuming ChromeDriver is in your $PATH:

```
% chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub
Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Now grab that port (9515) and update your nightwatch.json to dictate you want to use Chrome.  I am setting the default, but you could set up a Chrome-specific environment. Remove the "selenium" block from your nightwatch.json altogether and now tell nightwatch where it can find a running server **AND** what type of browser that is serving:

```
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": "http://localhost:8888/",

      "selenium_host": "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port": "9515", 

      "silent": true,
      "firefox_profile": false,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "__commentOut: chromeOptions" : {
              "args" : ["start-fullscreen"]
            }
      },
    }
  }
```

Using it this way works for me; I can run nightwatch to drive Chrome without a Java Selenium standalone server in-play. Again, this is on OS X using a ChromeDriver that is **always** running. I can't figure out how to get nightwatch to manage starting/stopping the ChromeDriver without adding the Java Selenium standalone server to the mix.

Answer (score 1):

Well Nightwatch.js runs it's tests against the Selenium server. The Selenium server is a Java-Servlet.

So to use Nightwatch.js you just "indirectly" need Java (it's not needed for Nightwatch.js, but for Selenium).

However you are able to use different languages as Selenium Client, since you are able to download different WebDriver Language bindings [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

++++++++++++++++++EDIT++++++++++++++++++

Those WebDrivers/bindings are independent of Nightwatch.js. You can use these WebDrivers/bindings without a Selenium server, if your tests and your browser run on the same machine. In this case you do not need Java, since the WebDriver runs the tests directly against a browser (this is further detailed [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp))

Nightwatch.js on the other hand definitelly requires java, because it needs the "Selenium-Standalone-Server" which is written in Java. As far as I know there are no other implementations for other languages, which is why it's not possible to run it without java.

Nightwatch sends HTTP requests to the Selenium-Standalone-Server (here comes java) and the server creates a session with the browser.

So to sum up: No Java --> No "Selenium-Standalone-Server" --> No testing with Nightwatch.js

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure we understand each other. You can use Selenium without using Java, there are official Selenium JavaScript bindings. My question was why Nightwatch.js uses Java, when driving a browser could be done without it. Well actually, my question was is there a way to use Nightwatch.js without installing Java. From you answer it looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

There is:

Specify in `global.js` file the following:

```
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

module.exports = {

before: function (cb) {
    chromedriver.start();
    cb();
},
after: function (cb) {
    chromedriver.stop();
    cb();
},
```

Go to `nightwatch.conf.js` specify the global path there

That way you selenium will be diverted via Chromedriver without you needing selenium on your machine.